# Componente vue no reconoce atributo de objeto

Tags: vue.js

Recien comienzo con vue. Tengo un componente en un archivo aparte.

```
<template>
    <section id="service-header" class="menu-ref" >
        <div class="container px-5">
            <div class="row px-5" >
                <div class="col-md-4 wow animated fadeInUp"  data-wow-dedlay="1s" data-wow-duration="4s">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <img class="img img-responsive img-service" src="{{servicio1.logo}}"  style="background-color: red">
                    </div>
                    <h2>{{logo}}</h2>
                    <p>{{servicio1.descripcion}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>    
            <hr>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['servicio1', 'logo'],
        data: function(){
            return {
                servicio: {
                    titulo: '',
                    descripcion: '',
                    logo: ''
                }
            }
        },
        computed: {
            getLogo: function(){
                return this.servicio.logo;
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

Cuando declaro mi componente en mi archivo blade.php lo hago de esta forma

```html
<services-component 
       v-for="servicio in {{$servicios}}"
       :key= "servicio.id"
       :servicio1= "servicio"
       :logo ="servicio.logo">
    </services-component>
```

puedo acceder en el componente a cualquier propiedad del objeto servicio1 excepto cuando estoy asigando el src de la imagen.  es decir aqui

```html
src="{{servicio1.logo}}"
```

no importa que trate de acceder directamente a la variable declara en props o a una propiedad computada.

cuando ejecuto en consola npm run watch me lanza este error.

**
src="{{servicio1.logo}}": Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of , use .**

cual es la razon y como solucionarlo .gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando pasas datos a otra vista como lo estas haciendo

```
:nombre="item.nombre"
```

Solo necesitas llamar al nombre que le declaras. En este caso:

```
{{ nombre }}
```

y tambien tenes que declarar que datos estas recibiendo en el archivo que recibe los datos.

```
props: ["nombre"],
```

En las etiquetas en las que se llaman a un dato tienen que tener :antes de la etiqueta, en este caso: `:src="item.logo"`.

Comment: gracias solucionado con :src="item.logo".

Comment: Marca mi pregunta como respuesta correcta para poder seguir ayudando.

Comment: Consejos @ElianMiranda: el término aceptado en la comunidad es **respuesta aceptada** y segundo pareciera un tanto una orden, es mejor **recomendarle** al OP que considere marcar tu aporte ya que eso es elección de el enteramente y la ayuda no debe depender que te marquen o no las respuestas como aceptadas